# Command CanExecute not changing

Tags: c#, wpf, button, command, icommand

This example isn't supposed to make sense, i'm just practicing.

I have this command:

```cs
        public class NewCommand : ICommand
        {
            public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
            {
                add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
                remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
            }

            public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
            {
                return !((string)parameter == "sample");
            }

            public void Execute(object parameter)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The New command was invoked");
            }
        }
```

and it works great (pressing `Button` opens message box), except changing `string` in `TextBox` does nothing. When `Button` should be blocked, it isn't.

This is my XAML and ViewModel:

```xml
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding TextB}"></TextBox>
        <Button Command="{Binding Path=NewCommand}" FontSize="128">New</Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

```cs
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            private string _textB;
            public ICommand NewCommand { get; set; }
            public string TextB
            {
                get => _textB;
                set
                {
                    if (_textB == value) return;
                    _textB = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TextB));
                }
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            public void OnPropertyChanged(string memberName)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(memberName));
            }
        }
```

Comment: I suggest [Relaying Command Logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic) as improvement for your `ICommand` implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CanExecute always return true, because `parameter` is null, and doesn't match `"sample"`. Bind CommandParameter:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TextB}"/>
<Button Command="{Binding Path=NewCommand, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding Path=TextB}"  
        FontSize="128" Content="New" />
```

Comment: Right, just found it after more digging. Thanks for help though, marking as solved.